# Insert and remove item from sub-array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert new data and remove data from MongoDB but don't know how.
It's a little bit complicated.
Could anyone teach me how to do this?

Example,
There are 3 students in Class1-1, and they take several different courses.

Alice: Math, Science, Music
Bob: Math, Music, Chinese
Carl: Music, Science

We store the data in mongodb like this:

```
{
    className: "1-1"
    students:["Alice","Bob","Carl"],
    subjects:[
        {"Math":["Alice","Bob"]},
        {"Science":["Alice","Carl"]},
        {"Music":["Alice","Bob","Carl"]},
        {"Chinese":["Bob"]}
    ] 
}
```

How do I **insert** a new student or **remove** a student?

**Insert a new student**

New student -->  Daniel: Math, English

**Step1.** Push "Daniel" to "students" array
**Step2.** Push "Daniel" to the array of subject
**Step2.1.** Push "Daniel" to the array of subjects.Math.
**Step2.2.** Create a new subject, subject.English, and push "Daniel" to the array of subject.English

The result would be

```
{
    className: "1-1"
    students:["Alice","Bob","Carl","Daniel"],
    subjects:[
        {"Math":["Alice","Bob","Daniel"]},
        {"Science":["Alice","Carl"]},
        {"Music":["Alice","Bob","Carl"]},
        {"Chinese":["Bob"]},
        {"Englsih":["Daniel"]}
    ] 
}
```

**Remove a student**: Bob

**Step1:** remove "Bob" from students array.
**Step2:** remove "Bob" from the array of subjects.
In the step2: there are two different situations.
**Situation1:** we know what subjects Bob takes in advance.
**Situation2:** we don't know what subjects Bob takes.

The result would be

```
 {
    className: "1-1"
    students:["Alice","Carl","Daniel"],
    subjects:[
        {"Math":["Alice","Daniel"]},
        {"Science":["Alice","Carl"]},
        {"Music":["Alice","Carl"]},
        {"Chinese":[]},
        {"Englsih":["Daniel"]}
    ] 
}
```

Can we remove the subject object if the array of subject is empty at the same time?

The result would be

```
 {
    className: "1-1"
    students:["Alice","Carl","Daniel"],
    subjects:[
        {"Math":["Alice","Daniel"]},
        {"Science":["Alice","Carl"]},
        {"Music":["Alice","Carl"]},
        {"Englsih":["Daniel"]}
    ] 
}
```

**We can change the subjects structure, and it would be easier to process**

```
{
    className: "1-1"
    students:["Alice","Carl","Daniel"],
    subjects:[
        {"subject": "Math", "student":["Alice","Daniel"]},
        {"subject": "Science", "student":["Alice","Carl"]},
        {"subject": "Music", "student":["Alice","Carl"]},
        {"subject": "Englsih", "student":["Daniel"]}
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you can simplify your scenario changing the document structure.

For example having one document for each class and subject.

```
{
    className : "1-1",
    subject : "Math",
    students : ["Alice","Bob"]
}
```

student array is easier to manage in this way.

Comment: This scenario is for the summary. We want to get the result as fast as possible 1) How many subjects the students take in this class? 2) Who takes this subject in this class?  This data is the simulation data, and the real data is related to the protein. It's a large scale data. We can change to subjects:[{subject: Math, students:[Alice,Bob..]}], but can't change to the structure as you said.